# Can you pin a symbol or layer to the bottom of an artboard in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app, interface-design, user-experience

I'm working with a footer symbol and I want it to always stay pinned to the bottom edge of my artboard, so when I lengthen or shorten my artboard when I'm adding content, it stays pinned to the bottom, but doesn't resize. It seems like there's a way to do this type of thing within a symbol, but not with layers or symbols on the artboard. I'm using Sketch 64.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the following steps.

1. Create a footer symbol with the container **bigger than the footer itself**. The footer has to be **pinned left, bottom, right and fix height** inside of the symbol :

[image]

2. Insert the symbol in the Artboard, make it the size of the Artboard, check **Adjust content on resize**. Then, you can lock the footer symbol not to be bothered with :

[image]

This way you don't have to do any manual resizing

Answer (score -1):

The only way I can think about it would be something like this:

- Create a symbol with the piece you want pinned to the bottom
- Add the symbol to your artboard, and set your artboard to "Adjust content on resize"

By doing this when you resize the artboard the symbol will automatically resize keeping the pinned element on the bottom. The downside to this is it will resize everything else on your artboard as well.

Otherwise, you could:

- Create a symbol with the piece you want pinned to the bottom
- Add the symbol to your artboard, turn OFF artboard "Adjust content on resize"
- Manually resize the symbol every time

This is the approach I take most often. I have a symbol with header and footer in it, header pinned to top, footer pinned to bottom. Then I resize in the artboard whenever my artboard size changes.